# UWP app crashes while performing an async method

Tags: exception, uwp, async-await, crash, mvvm-light

I have created two methods in my BaseViewModel (MVVMLight App) to perform any async    code with some logic:

```
    public async Task PerformOperation(Func<Task> action)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            await action?.Invoke();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // logging is here
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public async Task PerformOperation(params Operation[] actions)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        MultipleOperatrions = true;
        OperationStatuses = new ObservableCollection<OperationStatus>();

        try
        {
            foreach(var action in actions)
            {
                var status = new OperationStatus() { StatusText = action.StatusText };
                OperationStatuses.Add(status);

                try
                {
                    await action?.AsyncAction();
                    status.Success = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    status.Success = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    status.IsFinished = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // logging is here
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            IsBusy = false;
            MultipleOperatrions = false;
            OperationStatuses = new ObservableCollection<OperationStatus>();
        }
    }
```

My models:

```
public class Operation
{
    public Func<Task> AsyncAction { get; private set; }

    public string StatusText { get; private set; }

    public Operation(Func<Task> action, string statusText)
    {
        AsyncAction = action;
        StatusText = statusText;
    }
}
```

My code of calling the methods in the view model:

```
    ...
    private IAsyncCommand _buildCommand;
    public IAsyncCommand BuildCommand => _buildCommand ?? (_buildCommand = new AsyncCommand(Build));

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public async Task Build()
    {
        // IT WORKS
        // this method is used for performing only a single operation
        // await PerformOperation(async () => { await Task.Delay(3000); });

        // IT CRASHES THE APP
        // for many tasks
        await PerformOperation(new Operation(async () => { await Task.Delay(3000); }, "Preparing..."));
    }
    ...
```

So, if I call PerformOperation to call just only a single method - it works fine. But it doesn't for the method of performing of several operations - the application just crashes without any exception or messages. I subscribed in App.cs to UnhandledException event to catch it but the app just crashes.

Comment: Have you set breakpoint or added any logging to the internal catch that sets `status.Success = false`. That's where it looks like you'd see your exception if there is one happening.

Comment: Could you share a simple sample that I could test directly. This can quickly find and solve issue.